# TimeLine like iOS Path app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to make a timeline like this

[image: this]

I tried to make it and its working for `match_parent` contents but for less there is no bottom line here is the picture

[image: pic] 
and this is my XML code I use `ConstraintLayout` and I used `match_constraint` for bottom and top lines

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/circleImageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:text="125125125"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<View
    android:layout_width="0.6dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="#797979"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/circleImageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/circleImageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circleImageView" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
    android:layout_width="6dp"
    android:layout_height="6dp"

    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_bg"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.01"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.06999999" />

<View
    android:layout_width="0.6dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="#797979"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/circleImageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/circleImageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/circleImageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

can anyone please help me to fix this problem? I want to draw a bottom line even without `match_parent` content

Comment: @reza Amini whats application or sample you attach on your post?